# Iphone: How to move the tableview down to the navigation view?

Tags: iphone

I have a window project created, which has Tabbar controller, Navigation bar. And clicking on first tab bar item shows a Tableview. I have added a small rectangle view (width: 320; height: 35) under the navigation bar additionally to have some controls there. It is attached with top Navigation bar. But after attached a rectangle view under the navigation bar, first row of the table is not visible, because it is becoming under the rectangle view. How do i move the entire tableview down to fit starting from the rectangle view which i attached under the navigation bar. 
I tried moving tableview in xib file, but it doesn't reflected  when i run the app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by decreasing Content->Inset value.